# Redirecting after a AJAX form post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I am currently investigating an issue a friend came to me with. I really don't have a solid understanding of either `AJAX` or `jQuery`. Near from what I can tell, when this form is posted, it is going to the current `address/set_var.cgi` with the index of `94` and is being redirected to `currentaddress/scale405.html`. He wants to be able to set the address in the second input to an actual address like `www.google.com` so the user is redirected to a different site after the form post. I've tried looking in the `jQuery` and `AJAX` scripts and I am at a total loss.

if someone would like to take a look, its `www.gloryfeed.com`.

```
<form name="requestPrint" action="http:set_var.cgi" method="POST">
  <input name="value" type="hidden" size="8" value="1"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="page" value="scale405.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="index" value="94">
</form>
```

So I guess my question is, is there a way to format the `URL` that is entered into that value so it redirects properly without having to change the `AJAX` and `jQuery`?

Comment: Wait, so a .cgi file is a pear script? I don't even see that file present on the web server... Hmm... However, it does indeed work. He just want to redirect to an outside web address

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would like to do. However, both of us cannot seem to find that stupid file on the web server. Which probably means it's being imported from the net, but i don't see that either.  clearly, it is on there but cannot find it. This is by no means in my field of knowledge, just wanted to see if there was a reasonable workaround.

Comment: The point of using ajax is so you can submit forms without reloading pages...

If you're just going to redirect, why not just use your regular server side script to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect itself is very easy:

```
doc.location = redirect_url;
```

The `redirect_url` would come from the AJAX data. It depends on whether you get JSON or XML as data. If set, then redirect.

With XML you can use jQuery to retrieve the data. Maybe something like that (untested):

```
redirect = jQuery("redirect", result.jqxhr.responseXML);
```

You may have to handle all sorts of situations, the primary one being errors. If the form you just sent has a missing field, you probably want to generate an error instead of a redirect. But the basics is pretty simple as shown above.

I wrote a `server_access.js` script that handles redirects, errors, sending data both ways... It's a plugin part of [Snap! Websites](https://github.com/m2osw/snapwebsites/tree/master/snapserver-core-plugins/src/server_access).

---

As a side note, using a `Location: redirect_url` in the HTTP header won't help. The AJAX response won't ever trigger a redirect, which is by design.

Comment: Yes... be sure to use a switch to filter out any bad ( malicious ) requests, and only process the ones in your switch cases.